# How to zip files with a size limit?

Tags: linux, bash, gzip

I have a script that zip files from a folder. I want to make sure that the zipped file is not more than 10 MB. If the size is more than 10MB, it should create another ZIP file.

Is there any command (or other method )that can be used for this?

Comment: The question has the *gzip* tag but the text refers to *zip*, can you clarify? (The answers are divided between approaches based on the different formats.)

Comment: I cannot add zip into the tag thats why I used gzip, If you have a gzip method that I can fit with this problem, I can use that too.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use the "**split archive**" functionality of "**zip**" itself using the  "**--split-size**" option.

From "zip" manpage ("`man zip`"):

> (...)
>
> One use of split archives is storing a large archive on multiple remov‐
> able media.  For a split archive with 20 split files the files are typ‐
> ically named (replace ARCHIVE  with  the  name  of  your  archive)  AR‐
> CHIVE.z01,  ARCHIVE.z02,  ..., ARCHIVE.z19, ARCHIVE.zip.  Note that the
> last file is the .zip file.
>
> (...)
>
> -s splitsize
> --split-size splitsize
>
> Split size is a number  optionally  followed  by  a  multiplier.
> Currently  the  number  must  be an integer.  The multiplier can
> currently be one of k (kilobytes), m (megabytes), g (gigabytes),
> or  t  (terabytes).   As  64k is the minimum split size, numbers
> without multipliers default to megabytes.  For example, to  cre‐
> ate  a  split  archive  called  foo with the contents of the bar
> directory with splits of 670 MB that might be useful for burning
> on CDs, the command:
>
> ```
>                 zip -s 670m -r foo bar
> ```
>
> could be used.

So, **to create a split zip archive**, you could do the following (the "`-r`" is the "recursive" switch to include subdirectories of the directory):

`$ zip -r -s 10m archive.zip directory/`

**To unzip the file**, the "`zip`" manpage explains that you should use the "-s 0`" switch:

> (...)
>
> ```
>  zip -s 0 split.zip --out unsplit.zip
> ```
>
> will convert a split archive to a single-file archive.
>
> (...)

So, you first **"unsplit" the ZIP file** using the "-s 0" switch:

`$ zip -s 0 archive.zip --out unsplit.zip`

... and then you **unzip the unsplit file:**

`$ unzip unsplit.zip`

Comment: Your argument about using --out to unsplit is actually incorrect:

" -O (--output-file or --out) 
              zip inarchive.zip foo.c bar.c --out outarchive.zip
       reads  archive inarchive.zip, even if split, adds the files foo.c and bar.c, and writes the resulting archive to outarchive.zip.  If inarchive.zip is split then outarchive.zip defaults to the same split size.  Be aware that if
       outarchive.zip and any split files that are created with it already exist, these are always overwritten as needed without warning.  This may be changed in the future."

Answer (score 11):

```
tar -czvf - /path/to/files | split -b 10M - archive.tar.gz
```

Will give you a number of files:

```
archive.tar.gzaa

archive.tar.gzab

...
```

Which then can be uncompressed with:

```
cat archive.tar.* | tar -xzvf -
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I did it for a 5GB file (split into 1GB vs 10MB as OP asked)...

**Example:** To split a *5GB file* into *1GB files* to copy to a FAT32 USB (filename "FIVE_GB_FILE.ISO")

**Step 1:** zip the file (no compression, same directory as source)

```
zip -0 FIVE_GB_FILE.ZIP FIVE_GB_FILE.ISO
```

**Step 2**: split the 5GB zip file into 1GB zip files

```
zip -s 1000m SPLIT_5GB_FILES FIVE_GB_FILE.ZIP
```

Voila... you should have the following 1GB files (AND the original, AND the zip from step 1)

```
SPLIT_5GB_FILES.zip
SPLIT_5GB_FILES.Z01
SPLIT_5GB_FILES.Z02
SPLIT_5GB_FILES.Z03
SPLIT_5GB_FILES.Z04
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But, what to do when unzipping?

Comment: @maged-saeed pass unzip the first of the multi-zipped files and It automatically processes all of the children until finished.

Comment: @JayMarm Incorrect:
unzip ssm-confluent-linux_6.2.0.z01 
Archive:  ssm-confluent-linux_6.2.0.z01
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of ssm-confluent-linux_6.2.0.z01 or
        ssm-confluent-linux_6.2.0.z01.zip, and cannot find ssm-confluent-linux_6.2.0.z01.ZIP, period.

And when passing the LAST file:

Comment: @JayMarm:
unzip ssm-confluent-linux_6.2.0.zip 
Archive:  ssm-confluent-linux_6.2.0.zip
warning [ssm-confluent-linux_6.2.0.zip]:  zipfile claims to be last disk of a multi-part archive;
  attempting to process anyway, assuming all parts have been concatenated
  together in order.  Expect "errors" and warnings...true multi-part support
  doesn't exist yet (coming soon).
file #1:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  4